# Possible to hide SharePoint Date time Control Based on that Dropdown Selection?

Tags: sharepoint-server, datetimecontrol

I was  using  SharePoint Date time Control, I want to hide this user control.But date time control textbox is hiding but the Calendar image is not hiding.

```
 else if (document.getElementById('<%=ddlColumnName1.ClientID %>').value == 'RenewOrExpiryDate') {
                    document.getElementById('<%=dtRenewOrExpiryDate1.Controls[0].ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

i used this one but only it was hide Textbox of SharePoint Date time Control.
How can i hide both Image and textbox of SharePoint Date time Control.

Date time control if user does not select any date also it will select by default today date.How can i make date field is empty.

Before,It was like this. see this image after hiding only image display.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it OOTB form or custom?

Comment: no it is a custom form

Comment: add below css to your code, it will hide SharePoint Datetime controls

Comment: You should clearly state question. You have not mentioned you need to hide date time control on dropdown selection only

Comment: refer updated answer

Comment: I have updated my answer..please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, It will hide both textbox and image of `dtRenewOrExpiryDate` field

```
else if (document.getElementById('<%=ddlColumnName1.ClientID %>').value == 'RenewOrExpiryDate')
    {
    var dtRenewOrExpiryDate=document.getElementById('<%=dtRenewOrExpiryDate1.Controls[0].ClientID%>');
    $(dtRenewOrExpiryDate).hide();
    $(dtRenewOrExpiryDate).closest("td").next().hide();
    }
```

Comment: i cant hide tr because in one tr i have more use controls.within tr i have two drop downs,textbox,and three date-time control.SO i want to hide only one date time control based on that dropdown selection.

Comment: updated my answer..try it.

Comment: hi vishal actually its not a separate td.within one tr one td i have this two drop downs,textbox,and three date-time control.

Comment: Are you tried it. i think it will work. because SharePoint Date time Control will generate separate table for it at run time.

Comment: I tested it. its hiding both textbox and image. Date-time control will wrap into table on page load.

Comment: It will not hide any other controls.

Answer (score -1):

For your scenario, This will hide (text box and image of calendar both) . Tested

```
else if (document.getElementById('<%=ddlColumnName1.ClientID %>').value == 'RenewOrExpiryDate') {
          document.getElementById('<%=dtRenewOrExpiryDate1.Controls[0].ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById("<%= dtRenewOrExpiryDate1.ClientID%>" + "_dtRenewOrExpiryDate1DateDatePickerImage").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Generic : If you want to hide all date time controls on page, (text box and image of calendar both) Add below custom css to your code/Page :

```
.ms-dtinput{
    display : none !important;
}
```

Comment: It will hide all date time controls on form..So don't use this. Apart from this, the Question is asked for custom form not OOTB form.

Comment: this will hide whole page.Based on that dropdown selection only i want to hide date time control.

Comment: I did mentioned that It will hide all datetime controls, before @Suganya clearly mentioned that it is custom form and not ootb

Comment: What is meaning of downvoting if question was not clear stating

Comment: @VishalMPatil Doest that mean OOTB css overriding doesnt work in custom form ??

Comment: @Gaurravs. It will work on both OOTB as well as Custom form. but  the question is asked for hiding only specific date time control not all date-time controls.

Comment: Why did you raised 2nd concern then in your first comment, ??

Comment: I tried this but still the image is appearing  textbox only hiding.

Comment: debug your code and see if its actually going inside `else if` condition